# How to deal with http2-push and subdirectories?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http2, server-push

I have been developing a site with the following structure

- main site + htaccess

  - Fr subdirectory (for French)
  - En subdirectory (for English)
  - Assets subdirectory for images, js and css

The htaccess contains a http2 server push as follows:

```
<IfModule http2_module>
SetEnvIf Cookie "cssloaded=1" cssloaded
<filesMatch "\.([hH][tT][mM][lL]?)">
Header add Link "<assets/base/css/style.css>;rel=preload;as=style" env=!cssloaded
Header add Set-Cookie "cssloaded=1; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly" env=!cssloaded
</filesMatch>
```

The issue is that the server pushes the style.css also in the French and English subdirectories resulting in a 404 (and then proceeds to load the correct one without server push, being ../assets/base/css/style.css).

How to avoid this OR (preferably) push the file in all directories but pointing to the correct file?

Answer (score 0):

You're pushing a relative path style sheet:

```
Header add Link "<assets/base/css/style.css>;rel=preload;as=style" env=!cssloaded
```

Why not push an absolute one?:

```
Header add Link "</assets/base/css/style.css>;rel=preload;as=style" env=!cssloaded
```

Or, alternatively, use location or locationMatch instead of fileMatch:

```
<locationMatch "^/$">
Header add Link "<assets/base/css/style.css>;rel=preload;as=style" env=!cssloaded
Header add Set-Cookie "cssloaded=1; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly" env=!cssloaded
</locationMatch>
<locationMatch "^/en/$">
Header add Link "<../assets/base/css/style.css>;rel=preload;as=style" env=!cssloaded
Header add Set-Cookie "cssloaded=1; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly" env=!cssloaded
</locationMatch>
<locationMatch "^/fr/$">
Header add Link "<../assets/base/css/style.css>;rel=preload;as=style" env=!cssloaded
Header add Set-Cookie "cssloaded=1; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly" env=!cssloaded
</locationMatch>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's in the htaccess so locationmatch won't work ... The absolute path I didn't think of, but afraid that it would require an additional lookup (negating the speed advantage of the server push) but it's a good idea. I'll test it thanks!

Comment: Why would it require an extra lookup?

Comment: You are absolutely right, it doesn't. The absolute path suggestion works flawlessly by the way. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. I think you took this from my blog post (https://www.tunetheweb.com/performance/http2/http2-push/), as the config looked familiar :-) So checked that and it had the absolute path in it so copy paste error I guess!